# render problem (cycles is not showing in realtime)

Tags: cycles-render-engine

i have problem, i changed rendering to cycles but nothink happened. My rendered image is in cycles but i want to see  it in realtime render.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you select the render in the viewport?

[image]